How to Migrate DB with pg_transport while still having the PostGIS extension
I want to use pg_transport to migrate my PostgreSQL database from one RDS Instance to another RDS instance. My database is around 100 GB which contains spatial data (geom column) and uses the PostGIS extension. I read here that: No extension other than pg_transport must be enabled in the source database instance.
However I can't drop the PostGIS extension because it is used for many tables. Is there a way to keep the PostGIS extension? or is there a way like disable PostGIS, so I can still use pg_transport to migrate my database?
Additional question, if I force drop cascade PostGIS, will my geometry column be deleted too?
